# BoostrapVue: modify table to show items as inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

How can I modify the below code to make the items be inputs that the user has to enter?
Instead of the item being listed, I want to be able to have an input field instead.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // Note `isActive` is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
      fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'],
      items: [
        { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not too familiar with the table, but looking at the documentation you could try slots. Though... there is the warning in documentation `Avoid manipulating record data in place, as changes to the underlying items data will cause either the row or entire table to be re-rendered`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `v-slot:cell()`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fields: ['index', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age'],
      items: [
        { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.18.1/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.18.1/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template v-slot:cell(index)="{ index }">
      {{ index + 1 }}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:cell()="{ item, field: { key }}">
      <b-form-input v-model="item[key]" />
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Majed. What if i want to add an index column.. with the first row equal 1, 2nd row 2 and so on?

Comment: You're welcome, one way is to do the above